# Reading analog value Raspberry Pi

Tags: sensor, analog-to-digital

I am a newbie with the Raspberry Pi.
I want to measure Temperature Reading in 12/16 bit resolution. can someone guide me how CKT should be designed and How can read value using software.

usually arduino read analog voltage from 0-5VDC
& rasberry pi will read analog voltage from 0-3.3V

For better resolution we can use MCP3008 series module.

if i have sensor with 0-5Vdc , 0-10Vdc and 4-20mA current output.Let me know recommended ckt

Answer (score 1):

*MCP3008 is good for hobbyists.  You may also consider MCP3204, 3208 etc.  ADS1005, 1015 are also good.  HX711 is low noise.  If you have many places far away to sense temperature, you may like to consider DS18B20.*

***MCP3008***

[MCP3008 minimum current(resistors value)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98867/mcp3008-minimum-currentresistors-value/98970#98970)

***DS18B20***

[Pi can't find 5th DS18B20](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/pi-cant-find-5th-ds18b20/100244#100244)

***MCP3424***

[Reading analog sensor value of 0-10Vdc with 12/16bit resolution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99505/reading-analog-sensor-value-of-0-10vdc-with-12-16bit-resolution)

***ADS1115***

[Seeed ADC (ADS1115) with Raspberry Pi 3 B+to read voltage values using python3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98842/seeed-adc-ads1115-with-raspberry-pi-3-bto-read-voltage-values-using-python3)

***AD8232***

[can Raspberry Pi work exactly like Arduino? uploding arduino codes into raspberry pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98416/can-raspberry-pi-work-exactly-like-arduino-uploding-arduino-codes-into-raspberr)

***ADS1256***

[Separate SPI data](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99353/separate-spi-data)

***HX711***

[Connecting 4 HX711 to one Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96422/connecting-4-hx711-to-one-raspberry-pi)

***PCF8591 MCP3204***

[How to read ADC with low restance range](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99550/how-to-read-adc-with-low-restance-range)

***MCP3208***

[Reading Temp/Pressure with a single Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98824/reading-temp-pressure-with-a-single-raspberry-pi)

***PH-4502C pH meter (ADS1115/PCF8591/DS18B20)***

[Calibrate PH-4502C pH meter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96653/calibrate-ph-4502c-ph-meter)

***LTC1867***

[Reading only 0 from ADC using RPi SPI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98093/reading-only-0-from-adc-using-rpi-spi)

.END

Answer (score 0):

As commented in other answers, you can use for example the ADS1115, a 16bit AD converter. Adafruit has a simple yet great library for it: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-4-channel-adc-breakouts .

I've been using it on 3.3V. It is monitoring the PI 4's battery voltage (using a resistor divider to step down from ~12.6V to ~3V). It works via I2C and has 4 individual channels (or 2 differential).

I plan to also test the PCF8591 (but this is an 8bit one), also suppported by the same Afruit library mentioned above. Cool thing about the PCF8591 is it also has a DAC, meaning it can output voltage.